# Uploading a Laravel project to Google Cloud Problem

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, version, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to upload Laravel 5.6 project to google cloud the problem is that google cloud `php` version is `7.0.3` but `laravel 5.6` requires `php v7.1.3`.

I tried to change php version from composer.json file and update composer but if I type `php -v`, I also got:

```
PHP 7.0.30-0+deb9u1 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2018 13:50:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.30-0+deb9u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

anyone can help ?

Comment: Two options: Get a new host, or downgrade your version of Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about deploying to App Engine, I'd suggest you choose the standard app engine environment over the flexible environment. Then, in the app.yaml file,
set your preferred/required php version. Like this:

```
runtime: php73  # language of the app
# env: flex     # let app engine know we use flexible environment
```

app.yaml file in app engine allows you to set the environment for your project and more. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `composer.json` php version to 7.0.3 and the `Laravel version` then delete your `.lock` file then install your `composer.json`.

Hope this helps. Good luck